# Why does what appaears to be a Geomtric Series simplifiy to this?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

[enter image description here][1]

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k[(1-p)^k +p^k(1 -p)] =(1-p)p \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} [k(1-p)^{k-1} +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kp^{k-1}]$$

$$=(1-p)p + [\frac{1}{p^2} +\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}] =\frac{1-2p+2p^2}{p(1-p)}$$

Can someone please let me know how the 2 summed series simplified to $\frac{1}{p^2}$ and $\frac{1}{p-1}^2$

I suspect it to be a geometric series and I seem to have $\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{1-p}$

Comment: Please use mathjax formatting, as images can't be searched.

Comment: Before you ask please make sure you search on approach0.xyz. a similar questions has most certainly already been asked and answered here.

Comment: Because of the $k$ inside there, it is not geometric. $\sum p^{k-1}$ is geometric, but  $\sum k p^{k-1}$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** what happens when you differentiate the geometric series?